# No parameterless constructor defined for this object exception while using Unity Container

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, unity-container, ioc-container

I am getting the above exception while trynig to load a view.

I am using Unity to intialize my controller instance. Still getting the above error.

Here is my controller.

```
public class SiteController : Controller
{

    private ISiteRepository _repository;

    public SiteController(ISiteRepository repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    //
    // GET: /Site/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // GET: /Site/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }}
```

And here is my Global.asax.cs to

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ConfigApi(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }

    static void ConfigApi(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var unity = new UnityContainer();
        unity.RegisterType<SiteController>();
        unity.RegisterType<ISiteRepository, SiteRepository>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());

        config.DependencyResolver = new IocContainer(unity);
    }
```

Here is my SiteRepository class.

```
public class SiteRepository:ISiteRepository
{
    private readonly SampleMVCEntities _dbContext;

    public SiteRepository()
    {
        _dbContext = new SampleMVCEntities();
    }

    private IQueryable<SiteConfig> MapSiteConfig()
    {
        return _dbContext.SiteConfigs.Select(a => new SiteConfig
        {
            Name = a.Name,
            LinkColour = a.LinkColour,
            SiteLogo = a.SiteLogo,
            SiteBrands = a.SiteBrands.Select(b => new Models.SiteBrand { SiteId = b.SiteId, BrandId = b.BrandId })
        });
    }

    public IEnumerable<SiteConfig> GetAll()
    {
        return MapSiteConfig().AsEnumerable();
    }}
```

This is my error stack.

No parameterless constructor defined for this object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless
>   constructor defined for this object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this
>   object.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type,
>   Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
>   RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +114
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
>   Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   +232    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +83    System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +6    System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +55
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type 'Config.Controllers.SiteController'. Make sure that
>   the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +179
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +74
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +197    System.Web.Mvc.<>c_*DisplayClass6.b*_2() +49    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a()
>   +13    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7    System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action
>   action) +22
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +88
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +98
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +268    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

---

Can somebody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Your SiteController doesn't seem to have a parameterless constructor.  Have you tried adding one there yet?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't have a parameterless constructor. And I am injecting the dependency and I am also setting my custom DependencyResolver.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Web API **uses two separate dependency resolvers**.

For "regular" MVC controllers which are derives from `Controller` you need to use the `DependencyResolver.SetResolver`:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
```

For the Wep API controllers which are derives form `ApiController` you need to use the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver` as in your code.

So if you plan to use both type of controllers you need to register your container twice.

There is a good article how to setup Unity for both dependency resolver:

[Dependency Injection in ASP.NET MVC 4 and WebAPI using Unity](http://netmvc.blogspot.hu/2012/04/dependency-injection-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html)